# Bootstrap Typeahead elements dom cleaning

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, typeahead

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to style and script my website.

My website is powered by Ajax, so navigating just loads different Views into a content-element .

These Views sometimes contain Typeaheads and Datepickers, but the problem is that Typeahead and Datepicker appends itself to the Body of my website.
So when navigating to another View (emptying the content-element), these Typeahead- and Datepicker-elements remain in my DOM, stacking up over time.

My only solution at the moment is to clean up on every new ajax request, like this:

```
$('.typeahead, .datepicker').remove();
```

Comment: This is as far as i can see the right solution. For other bootstrap plugins, like `tooltip` and `popover`, the elements are cleaned on `('hide')`, but typeahead adds an `<ul>` -structure that is regenerated once. However, it is an issue - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5142, maybe in next version?

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks, i guess il just stick with the manual cleaning, until future builds of bootstrap where this could be fixed.